# Problems with angular-modal-service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use the angular modal service to display a modal with an inline template, but I get an error.  What am I missing?  I just want to display a simple message in the modal.  Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhcsg6Lk/

**Page**

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/master/dst/angular-modal-service.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">

    <h3>Angular Modal Service</h3>
     <a class="btn btn-default" href ng-click="show()">Show a Modal</a>

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['angularModalService']);

    app.controller('Controller', function($scope, ModalService) {

$scope.test="outer scope"
    $scope.show = function() {
        ModalService.showModal({
            template: "{{test}}",
            controller:  function() {
                  this.test="test scope";
            },
            controllerAs : "modal"
        })
    }
 })
```

**ERROR:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to access test as `{{modal.test}}` since you have **controllerAs**  syntax.

http://jsfiddle.net/jvara30w/

According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service#showmodal-options), if you use **template**, you will need to provide **raw HTML**.

```
template: "<div>{{modal.test}}</div>",
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.test` is in the scope now. Kindly remove the "" from here. You are making it a string.

`template: {{test}},`

**UPDATE:**

Template is basically the view for the modal/overlay. I don't think it can be a string/text.

You would have to pass an absolute/relative path to an html file, or the html code itself, which inside would contain the string/text in `<p>{{model.test}}</p>` to display the message you want.

Comment: that generates an error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {{test}}.

Comment: ok, check out the fiddle now.  I needed an element: <div>{{test}}</div>.  though now the issue is that it does not act as a modal

Comment: please check its not the right fiddle. it doesn't have your code.

Comment: nope, still not the correct fiddle. You would need this in your code: `<div>{{modal.test}}</div>` as @Win pointed out.

Comment: I think I got it now.  1) I was missing a wrapping element.  2) you need to call modal.element.modal();.